# ASP.NET React Redux Template + _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to develop website with React front-end features and Asp.net for backend and some asp.net views for front-end. I don`t want to use React for the whole application. When I started new project, I used prepared ASP.NET React Redux Template by Visual Studio 2019. Everythink would be fine, but I cant find _Layout.cshtml.

Why do I need this file?

When I choose classic Asp.net mvc template, I can find in this file imports of css, js and also packages like bootstrap.

f.e:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

If I didn`t need classic asp.net views, the template would be helpful. How can I fix it, or where to import files/packages usable also for views?

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.NET Core + React templates by Microsoft, the Layout is not handled in the back-end with ASP but in the front-end with React. In the ClientApp/src/components folder, you will find a Layout.js file for this usage.

However, nothing stops you to create a partial view _Layout.cs and use Razor Pages / MVC as a React overlay. This way, every page should be handled with an ASP controller. Inside them you would add an empty HTML tag to place your React App if you need it.

In the ClientApp/src/index.js file, you will find the following line:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
```

You need to replace the element ID by the one where you want to render your React application in the DOM.

---

But typically, when using ASP with React, the front-end is left entierly to React. ASP is only useful for API controllers handling AJAX requests coming from React, and interacting with a database using Entity Framework.

Comment: I guess you are right, but It is not just about to change root element. It is appended to index.html in ClientApp/public/index.html, so it requires another changes and I don`t know which ones. I want to use same principle of Layout as it is in MVC model. So there is @RenderBody() where all content (views or react) should be rendered.

Comment: `index.html` is used for React startup, you can remove it in the app manifest. MVC routing is done server-side and hence has priority on top of `react-router`: you can create your own MVC controller and map it to your views

Comment: Also you will need to ensure that controller with views or razor pages are enabled in your Startup.cs file

Comment: Last, if you want to configure all of your routing by hand, you might find simpler to use a standalone express server alongside with kestrel/IIS.